# docker commands failing in jenkins shell step

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed docker on my RHEL slaves

and have given permissions to "tomcat" user

```
sudo usermod -aG docker tomcat
```

I am able to run this command "docker run hello-world" as tomcat user on the box directly, but when I am running the same through Jenkins its failing

```
Running Prebuild steps
[docker-test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5880049234473840635.sh
+ whoami
tomcat
+ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 96d83a5/1.12.6
+ docker run hello-world
/usr/bin/docker-current: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: is Jenkins itself running in a docker container?

Comment: @Sebastian No, Jenkins master and slaves are not running in a docker container

Comment: when you ssh to the slave are you able to run the docker command?

Comment: @Sebastian YES , when I ssh to the slave I am able to run docker commands using tomcat user

Comment: @devops - Try to disconnect & reconnect the slave again. I guess this may happen if you haven't created a new session post adding user to docker group.

Comment: @Sebastian I  reconnected the slave, but no luck :(

Comment: Do you use the same user as jenkins when you connect over SSH and run commands manualy?

Answer (score 0):

you give the permission to "tomcat" user..
Is it your jenkins ssh user? (user used to connect on slave?)
if yes, you must restart your jenkins (i had this problem)

else you must give permission to the user used to connect on slave and restart your jenkins